# What is the difference between base_grand_total and base_total_invoiced?

Tags: magento2, sales-order

The MySql table `sales_order` contains `base_total_invoiced` and `base_grand_total`, what is the (technical and semantic) difference between these two values?

Answer (score 1):

**base_grand_total** is the total of all ordered items in base currency of store.

**base_total_invoiced** os the total of all invoiced items from ordered items in base currency of store.

Comment: can you give me an example where these two values are different?